# Wi-Fi connected, but not connected to Internet

Tags: wireless

I am using 12.04 on a Dell Vostro 1014. I have been using wifi in this laptop previously, it was working well then. But now I got a new wifi connection at my home and it is not working. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try to turn your wifi off and on again. I'm having the same problem since 12.04 sometimes. I was to lazy to look into it though. I was just thinking it maybe the same error.

Comment: i tried doing it...it doesn't work! i can see my wifi signal is high and perfect, but cant access the internet, even thru, ethernet cable it is unable to connect!

Comment: Does your new connection have the same SSID (that is the name) of the old one?

Comment: Can you connect with another computer? Is DHCP (automatic connection) enabled on your router?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't information given in the question, but if the new wifi connection uses the same name as the previous one but uses different configuration options, you could try the following:

1. Click the network icon and choose "Edit connections"
2. Find the wireless connection in question and delete it
3. Try connecting again